# What is the shortcut key to back to the previous tab?

Tags: eclipse

For example, after clicking open declaration, is there a shortkey which let me back to the previous tab?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> to go back.

Answer (score 21):

By next tab, you probably mean the "Previous File".

By default switching between open files (called "Editors" in eclipse parlance) can be done by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>

This is configurable, so if you find this combination inconvenient (like me) you can change it in the Preferences: `General -> Keys`. Look for `Next Editor` and `Previous Editor`

(I have mapped them to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.)

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

to view all shortcuts and from them you can have your previous tab shortcut.

Comment: Not a specific answer.Asked for **Aluminium** you gave **Bauxite**

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about switching between open files, you can do this using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd>

If it is about navigating back & forth to the last modification, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇨</kbd> (**right arrow**) and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>⇦</kbd>(**left arrow**)

Comment: what is the MAC version of it ?