# Eclipse: navigate to previous file visited

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

Does Eclipse have a command or setting for navigating to the previous *file* visited? The "Backward History" navigation command (alt-left) goes to the previous "important location" you visited;  I don't want this.  I don't want to visit multiple locations in the same file. I want to skip to the prior file, even if I've visited multiple locations in the current file.

Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what-is-the-shortcut-key-to-back-to-the-previous-tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297456/what-is-the-shortcut-key-to-back-to-the-previous-tab), [how-to-navigate-to-the-last-cursor-position-in-eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313308/how-to-navigate-to-the-last-cursor-position-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 4):

Click `Windows > Preferences`. Set short cut for **Back** command note this is not **Backward History(Alt+Left)**  also give attention on the scope of the command in **When** column. Avoid short cut duplications.

[image]

In addition or more info

1. You can jump to the last modified location by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>.
2. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> to cycle through opened editors.
3. Refer [Retain previous open file tab under visible tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255389/retain-previous-open-file-tab-under-visible-tabs) and [Eclipse tabs repositionning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578197/eclipse-tabs-repositionning). Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PageDown</kbd>

Comment: The 'Back' command does work. I binds a shortcut key to this command, and when I press the key inside the active Java editor, the command is not triggered. It seems that no command handler is activated, and the key event is sent directly to the StyledText control.

Comment: Yes, it does the same thing for me -- I bound alt+left to "Back", and now it does nothing.  Also, the left arrow in my toolbar seems to be bound to "Backward History."

Answer (score 0):

The 'Next Editor' command may help you quickly navigate to the most recently used editor, although it does not support re-opening closed editors. To assign a key binding to it, simply open 'Preferences' dialog and navigate to 'General' - 'Keys'.

[image: Eclipse Key Binding Preference For 'Next Editor' Command]

Comment: `The 'Next Editor' command may help you quickly navigate to the most recently used editor` **Its wrong**

Comment: check it. Open 3 files. Visit 1 then visit 3. Activate any other view then press this short cut it will take you to file 1 NOT to 3 which is MOST RECENT.

Comment: 'Activate any other view then ....' <- Concept stealing. We're talking about "editors" here. Though a view is activated, the editor 3 is still regarded as "the active editor". So it's absolutely right to navigate to the "most recently used editor" which is editor 1.